# Should files from a base Docker image be present in a derived image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm creating a Dockerfile that uses a base image: dockerfile/rabbitmq.

In the Dockerfile for rabbitmq there's a line to install a script into the image:

```
ADD bin/rabbitmq-start /usr/local/bin/
```

In my Dockerfile I don't have this line.  I have my own ADD lines.

When I run the image all the rabbitmq binaries and config are there, along with my stuff, but there's no rabbitmq-start script anywhere.

Why isn't it present in my image?  (If I run the base image dockerfile/rabbitmq the file is there, of course.)  Are ADD's not "inherited" to derived images?

Comment: The files from the base image should be visible (after all, `dockerfile/rabbitmq` is itself based on an Ubuntu image, and those files are demonstrably present).  Can you post your actual Dockerfile?

Comment: Dockerfile here: https://github.com/gzoller/world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

1. I cloned [dockerfile/ubuntu](http://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu) and built that locally,
2. I cloned [dockerfile/rabbitmq](http://github.com/dockerfile/rabbitmq) and built that locally,
3. I cloned [your repository](https://github.com/gzoller/world) and built that locally.

Booting a shell in your image:

```
docker run -it --rm gzoller/world bash
```

I see both the `rabbitmq-start` script added by the `rabbitmq` image as well as the `start` script installed in your image:

```
[ root@d0044b91278e:/data ]$ ls /usr/local/bin/
rabbitmq-start  start
```

Comment: Interesting...  My first cut I didn't build ubuntu and rabbitmq but just downloaded these from the repo.  Following what you have here, my next attempt I wiped everything clean and cloned all 3 repos and built them in order.  Now the rabbitmq-start file is present.  There must be a subtle difference between what's in docker hub and github.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no `dockerfile/rabbitmq` image in docker hub: `Error: image dockerfile/rabbitmq:latest not found`